# Undefined reference with GLUT for MinGW

Tags: c, windows, opengl, gcc, glut

Here is my directory:

```
graphics/
    glut.h
    glut32.dll
    glut32.lib
    simple.c
```

Here is my program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include "glut.h"


void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(-0.5,-0.5);
        glVertex2f(-0.5,0.5);
        glVertex2f(0.5,0.5);
        glVertex2f(0.5,-0.5);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutCreateWindow("simple");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

When I try to compile using the following command

```
 gcc simple.c -o MyProg glut32.lib -lopengl32 -lglu32
```

I get the following errors:

```
C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Temp\ccehzclV.o:simple.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `__imp___glutInitWithExit'
C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Temp\ccehzclV.o:simple.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `__imp___glutCreateWindowWithExit'
C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Temp\ccehzclV.o:simple.c:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to `__imp___glutCreateMenuWithExit'
C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Temp\ccehzclV.o:simple.c:(.text+0x162): undefined reference to `__imp_glutDisplayFunc'
C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Temp\ccehzclV.o:simple.c:(.text+0x16b): undefined reference to `__imp_glutMainLoop'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried every answer I can find, I've reinstalled MinGW, and I've reinstalled tdm-gcc. Nothing has worked, I'm hoping someone can shine some light on this.

EDIT: I've also added glut32.dll to system32 with no luck.

Comment: Can you give this a try : `gcc simple.c -o MyProg -lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lmingw32`

Comment: @ssd Now getting the error: `C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglut32`

Comment: Add the path : `gcc simple.c -o MyProg -lc:\path\to\the\file\glut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lmingw32`. One more correction: once you compile it cleanly, you may need to move (or copy) the `glut32.dll` file(s) into the executable path (`\Debug` or `\Release`).

Comment: That `glut32` in the `-lc:\path\to\the\file\glut32` part is `glut32.lib` (do not type the `.lib` extension in the compilation line). However, the file you need to copy into the executable files folder path is the `glut32.dll`.

Comment: @ssd Can't seem to find the path: `gcc simple.c -o MyProg -l C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\graphics\glut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lmingw32` returns the error: `C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\Users\Jake\Desktop\graphics\glut32`

Comment: Ok! I have a solution: `glut32.lib` and `glut32.dll` etc are pre-compiled to work with **Microsoft C**. For **mingw**, you need to; (1) either compile the library on your own, which will produce a `glut32.a` file (extension for Microsoft libs are `.lib` and extension for mingw libs are `.a`; mingw searches a `glut32.a` file and that is why it returns that it can not find the library) (2) or use [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/). Not sure 100% but I think the same code will work for both.

Comment: [Here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Compile_the_OpenGL_Utility_Toolkit_GLUT_for_Win32_with_MinGW) is a brief explanation for compiling library `glut32.a` with mingw on your own.

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/) web site, you can download the **freeglut** binaries pre-built with **MinGW**. You need to download the "*freeglut 3.0.0 MinGW Package*", not the "*freeglut 3.0.0 MSVC Package*" which is built for Microsoft C.

Extract the `include` and `lib` directories into your application directory, so you can use relative path. I've downloaded & tested; these *freeglut* files work just like the *glut* files, as expected. The compilation command line should read:

`gcc simple.c -o MyProg -I"path/to/include/" -L"path/to/lib/" -lfreeglut -lopengl32`

And, if you're compiling with 64 bits:

`gcc simple.c -o MyProg -I"path/to/include/" -L"path/to/lib/x64/" -lfreeglut -lopengl32`

p.s.
Make sure you've extracted the `freeglut.dll` file into your executable directory as well.